# Integral with complex exponential

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve for an integral of the following for 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{exp}(2\pi j\ z a)-1}{2\pi\ j z} \text{exp}(-2\pi j z T)\, dz$$

where $a, T$ are positive numbers.

I tried to use the int function in MATLAB to integrate symbolically and MATLAB seems not able to compute it.

Do I have to use complex analysis to solve this kind of problem? If yes, can you please guide me through?

Thanks

Comment: Split the integral in two parts. Then use a semicircular contour with small indents around the origin. Choose the semicircle in the upper plane if the imaginary part of your exponents is positive. Otherwise close in the lower halfplane. Do this for both integrals seperatly.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142276/fourier-transform-of-heaviside/1142558#1142558

Comment: If i'm not totally mistaken the result should be $-(\text{sign}[a-T]+1)/2$

Comment: thank u @tired but how did you arrive to that?

Comment: Follow my comments 1 and 2

Comment: this integral arises in the link i shared above. It is more or less line three without the imaginary part symbol

Comment: but wouldnt the imaginary part change the whole thing... im not sure i understand how to proceed @tired but thanks anyways i will keep on thinking about it

Comment: if anything fails, i can give you a solution tomorrow :)

Comment: awesome thanks i appreciate it alot @tired

Comment: I am very sorry I dont seem to understand how to even split the integral :(... @tired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's see...

In a first step we rewrite the integral as

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (a-T)q}}{2\pi i q}dq-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i qT}}{2\pi i q}dq
$$

First thing we note that both integrals have a singularity of order $1$ at the origin. This means that the integrals are not defined in the usual sense, but have to be interpreted as Cauchy principal part integrals denoted by $P\int=\int_R^{}$.

Now let's try to apply Complex analysis to the first integral. Therefore we look  at the function $f(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi i(z-T)}}{2\pi z}$ where $z$ is now a complex variable.

If $0<a-T$, $f(z)\rightarrow 0$ in the whole upper half plane (For a formal proof of this, apply the Lemma of Jordan) we therefore can write according to Cauchys theorem
$$
\underbrace{\int_{SC_+}f(z)dz}_{=0}+ \underbrace{(-i)\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\pi}^{0}f(\epsilon e^{i\phi})\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi}_{\text{small cemircircle to avoid the singularity}}+\underbrace{P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (q-T)}}{2\pi i q}dq}_{\text{the integral we are interested in}}=0
$$
Here $SC_+$ denotes a big semicircle in the upper half plane. The second integral can now be easily calculated.
$$
(-i)\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\pi}^{0}f(\epsilon e^{i\phi})\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi=-i\int_{\pi}^{0}d\phi=-1/2$$

And we can conclude that
$$
P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (q-T)}}{2\pi i q}dq=1/2 \quad \text{if} \quad a>T
$$

Applying the same analyis to the case were $0<a-T$, we have yo keep in mind, that we now have to close our contour in the lower half plane.

$$
\underbrace{\int_{SC_-}f(z)dz}_{=0}+ \underbrace{i\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\pi}^{0}f(\epsilon e^{i\phi})\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi}_{\text{small cemircircle to avoid the singularity}}+\underbrace{P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (a-T)q}}{2\pi i q}dq}_{\text{the integral we are interested in}}=0
$$

Note the missing minus sign in front of the second integral. It stems from the fact that we now going around the singularity in counter clockwise direction.
As a result we get

And we can conclude that
$$
P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (a-T)q}}{2\pi i q}dq=-1/2 \quad \text{if} \quad a<T
$$

Or, putting both results together,

$$
P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (a-T)q}}{2\pi i q}dq=\text{sign}[a-T]/2
$$

You can now apply a very similar analysis to the second integral (somehow easier because $T>0$ and therefore no case deception) with the result that

$$
-P\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i qT}}{2\pi i q}dq=1/2
$$

So the complete integral is just given by

$$
(1+\text{sign}[a-T])/2
$$

I hope everything is clear now :)

Comment: Great explanation thanks!

Comment: may i ask why $\underbrace{(-i)\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\pi}^{0}f(\epsilon e^{i\phi})\epsilon e^{i\phi}d\phi}_{\text{small cemircircle to avoid the singularity}}=-1/2$ @tired I appreciate it