# wrong answer in calculating the principal value of integral using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, cauchy-principal-value

I have read the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137156/improper-integrals-with-singularities-on-the-real-axis-complex-variable) and it has helped a lot but for$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-2}dx$, I get the wrong answer.
[I used this contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ADxp.png)
\begin{align}
P.V\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-2}dx&=\int_{C\ \cup P\ \cup L_1\cup L_2}^{}\frac{1}{z-2}dz-\int_{C}^{}\frac{1}{z-2}dz-\int_{P}^{}\frac{1}{z-2}dz\\
&=0-0-(-i\pi)=i\pi
\end{align}
As you can see the answer is wrong because it's complex even though it's the result of a real integral.
And I suppose that we can't be using $P.V=\text{Re}(i\pi)$ because there's no $\cos(ax)$ in the numerator.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\int_C\to0$ as the radius tends to $\infty$. Just because it works that way in the examples you've seen doesn;t mean it works here - how did you _show_ $\int_C\to0$???

Comment: Btw using complex to find this PV seems silly. What is $\int_{2-R}^{2-\delta}+\int_{2+\delta}^{2+R}$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I guess you're right, I probably have to use some other lemma to determine the value of the integral, and yes it's much easier to find the PV but I just wanted to learn the method with different examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that the integral over $C$ is wrong.  It not zero.

Suppose that $C$ were a semicircle given by $z-2=100\exp(i\theta), 0\le\theta\le\pi$.  You evaluate the integral over this path, what do you get?  Can you see that the result will be independent of the radius of the large semicircle?